# How can I refactor these unless statements to make the block more efficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a "current" class to the following set of links based on if there is an "order" param in the URL. (ie. example.com/photos?order=views). I need some help refactoring this so it's not so burly.

```
<% unless params[:order] != 'created_at' %>
    <%= link_to "Recently Posted", photos_path, :class => 'current' %> 
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Recently Posted", photos_path %> 
<% end %>
<span class="pipe">|</span> 
<% unless params[:order] != 'comments' %>
    <%= link_to "Most Commented", photos_path + "?order=comments", :class => 'current' %> 
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Most Commented", photos_path + "?order=comments" %> 
<% end %>
<span class="pipe">|</span> 
<% unless params[:order] != 'views' %>
    <%= link_to "Most Viewed", photos_path + "?order=views", :class => 'current' %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Most Viewed", photos_path + "?order=views" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example you can use helper:

```
<%= link_to_photos_with_order 'created_at', "Recently Posted" %>
<span class="pipe">|</span>
<%= link_to_photos_with_order 'comments', "Most Commented" %>
<span class="pipe">|</span>
<%= link_to_photos_with_order 'views', "Most Viewed" %>
```

```
def link_to_photos_with_order order_by, title
  url = photos_path(:order => (order_by != 'created_at' ? order_by : nil))
  unless params[:order] != order_by
    link_to title, url, :class => 'current'
  else
    link_to title, url
  end
end
```

Another way is to use hash with order_by => title but it is uglier

Answer (score 1):

Extract the logic into a helper:

```
def link_to_ordering(params, ordering, title)
  css_class = params[:order] == ordering ? 'current' : ''
  link_to(title, photos_path(:order => ordering), :class => css_class)
end
```

Then just call e.g.:

```
<%= link_to_ordering(params, "Most Commented", "comments") %>
```

in your views.

Comment: I prefer this version, except just change photos_path + "?order=#{ordering}" to photos_path(:order => ordering)